# Why is form login principal null inside an Iframe? Same Site None cookies not working for Safari and Chrome 80

Tags: spring-boot, google-chrome, spring-mvc, iframe, spring-security

I am trying to enable my Spring Boot website within an `iframe`. I have security config, request filter, form login and OAuth2. My form login works well from browser but as soon as I logged in from `iframe` I can see `JSESSIONID` is `null` for the same users logged in from browser.

Log for `iframe`:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=test@example.com, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
```

Log for browser:

```
[Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=test@example.com, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=04E5DB0982A859E5C215294EF96814FD], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_MANAGER, ROLE_USER]]]
```

Below is my security config:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/app_resources/**", "/signup", "/favicon.ico", "/login", "/logout", "/signup",
                            "/oauth2/authorization/**", "/pages/**", "/login/oauth2/code/**", "/login/oauth2/code/**",
                             "/product/authenticate", "/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/auth")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .failureHandler(authenticationfailure())
            .successHandler(new AuthSuccessHandler()).permitAll()
        )
        .logout(out -> out
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
        )
        .sessionManagement()                         
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider())
        .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/auth")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/homesuccess")
            .successHandler(new AuthSuccessHandler());

    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable();
    return http.build();
}
```

Below is my `AuthenticationSuccesHandler`:

```java
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("onAuthenticationSuccess >>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+authentication.toString());
    request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(604800);
    RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
}
```

Not really sure what went wrong inside an `iframe`. I can see my login page, I can see the user password token object in `AuthennticationSuccessHandler` but after redirecting it to dashboard suddenly principal object becomes `null` in security filter.

MVC config:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        VersionResourceResolver versionResolver = new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**/*.js",
                "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app_resources/**", "/favicon.ico", "/firebase-messaging-sw.js", "/manifest.json",
                "/salesken.png")
                .addResourceLocations("/assets/js/",
                        "/assets/css/","/assets/img/","/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)).resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(versionResolver);

    }   
    
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("pages/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }   
}
```

Even when I am trying to put authentication object in session, this object is not set and its value is `null` in the request filter.

[image]

Comment: what can be root caue of this. How come its working in firefox only. I have checked in Safari as well its not working there.

Comment: Different browsers have different rules about what is allowed and these change over time. It’s late here - I will put together a fix first thing tomorrow - in about 10 hrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome uses 'Lax' as the [default same-site cookie policy](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592). This [prevents the browser for using the cookie in the iFrame](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/35313442/google-analytics-blocked-in-iframe-due-to-%E2%80%9Csamesite%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%9Csecure%E2%80%9D-setting-of-cookies?hl=en).

To fix this by setting the SameSite flag to none with Spring Boot 2.5.0 on, add the following:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.CookieSameSiteSupplier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SameSiteNoneConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CookieSameSiteSupplier applicationCookieSameSiteSupplier() {
        return CookieSameSiteSupplier.ofNone();
    }
}

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Only works with https because the cookie must be secure. Spring Boot session cookies are already httpOnly.

Spring Boot pre-2.5.0 does not have a CookieSameSiteSupplier so the following must be created. Requires Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE and up.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SameSiteInjector {

  private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer = applicationContext.getBean(DefaultCookieSerializer.class);
    cookieSerializer.setSameSite("none");
  }
}
```

with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To do this on Tomcat - from 8.5.42+. Edit %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/context.xml, update CookieProcessor element on following lines say for setting SameSiteCookies in HTTP response headers's set-cookie.

```
<CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor" sameSiteCookies="none" />
```

Because you are editing `%TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/context.xml` it will do this for all installed webapps. To avoid this you need to hack the META-INF folder and create a context.xml and put the above snippet within.

Comment: My Spring boot project is running inside tomcat server. Its not embeded Tomcat , Will it work or do i need to do same setting in tomcat level ?

Comment: I have attache a screenshot in question. I am running my application on ngrok and using Iframe of w3school website. Still not able to logged in Chrome Browser. Is it cache ?

Comment: The cookie response header looks correct! Don't think it's the cache but clear it anyway. Inspect the Cookies in Chrome developer tools after a login from the iframe and see if populated.

Comment: If w3school is https and the iframe is not then the cookie is not secure and this will break.

Comment: i guess its due to ngrok or cache , on server it works well

Comment: In Local machine  CookieSameSiteSupplier.ofNone is not working, its workinng only on server

Comment: Facing issues in Safari. As Safari is Blocked a frame with origin. Same Site none is not working in Safari

Comment: Versions of Safari on MacOS 10.14 and all browsers on iOS 12 are affected by this bug which means that SameSite=None is erroneously treated as SameSite=Strict, e.g. the most restrictive setting.

Comment: Same for Chrome after v80

Comment: what should we do now ?

Comment: How to set SameSite Cookie as both None & Secure.